# Aws Amplify bad substitution of node image

Tags: yaml, aws-amplify

Here is my `amplify.yaml`

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
        - echo "${secrets.github_ssh_key}" > ~/.ssh/ssh.key
        - chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/ssh.key
        - export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/ssh.key"
        - ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        - git submodule update --init --recursive
        - yarn install
    build:
      commands:
        - yarn run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

I am using `public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:18` image for the build.
But I cannot access any key stored in `$secrets`. When I try I see `bad substitution` warning.

I tried to parse parameter with `jq` bu I got `yum:command not found` error.

```
- yum install jq -y
- echo "github_ssh_key=$(echo "$secrets" | jq -r '.github_ssh_key')" >> .env
- echo "$github_ssh_key"
```

Any suggestion?